# Flutter Application does not render when in app switcher

Tags: flutter

To keep it short and simple, when ever a flutter application is in main focus, it renders its widgets.

Although on IOS, when the app switcher is opened ( doubling tapping the home button twice on iPhones 8<= and swiping up on iPhones 10+ ) it completely stops rendering.

Here is a [link](https://streamable.com/1g5hpi) to better understand the situation. The first part of the video displays a Flutter application that is being scrolled.

The scrolling behaviour stops immediately after jumping into the app switcher, although Instagram continues to scroll whilst in the app switcher.

If any one has any idea how to achieve this, that would be appreciated.